# Malloc error when comparing arrays of bytes

Tags: c, openssl, malloc

I can't figure out where my code is going wrong. I know there is allocation error in my function getit() but I can't figure out why! Any help is appreciated.

What my program does is hash a message into one array. Then, I have a random word generator that makes a string and hashes them. My program will then compare the hashes and keep making words until the hash matches the origional.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <openssl/evp.h>
 #include <string.h>

void randString(int length, char* s);
void getit(unsigned char rando[], unsigned char hash[]);
char* mess1 = "Test Message";
unsigned char match[3];
int boolean = 0; 
unsigned char orHash[3];
unsigned char raHash[3];
int counter = 0;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    srand(time(NULL));
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
     const EVP_MD *md;
     unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
     int md_len, i;


     OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

     md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256");

     mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
     EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
     EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess1, strlen(mess1));
     EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
     EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
     strcpy(match,md_value);
     strcpy(orHash,match); 
     printf("Digest is: ");
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         printf("%02x", match[i]);
     printf("\n");


   while(boolean < 3){
    char* qt = malloc(strlen(mess1) * sizeof(char));
    randString(strlen(mess1),qt);
     mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
     EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
     EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, qt, strlen(mess1));
     EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
     EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
     strcpy(raHash,md_value);
     getit(raHash, orHash);
    }

     exit(0);
 }

 void randString(int length, char* s) {
    const char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        s[i] = alpha[rand()%(int)(sizeof(alpha) -1)];
    }
    s[length] = '\0';
 }

void getit(unsigned char rando[], unsigned char hash[]){
    counter += 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         printf("%02x", rando[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if (rando[i] != hash[i]){
                printf("%d: The hashes don't match\n", counter);
        boolean = 0;
                break;
            }
            boolean += 1;
        if(boolean == 3){
            printf("Match Found!");

        }    
        }
}
```

The Error I get is as follows:

```
hash: malloc.c:2392: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

The code breaks at trial 505 everytime (finished comparing trial 504) trying the see if the two arrays match so that might help.

Comment: Are you on a machine where you can use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?  If so, use it.  Your error message diagnoses that you are abusing allocated memory somehow.  You can assume that the library is clean if used correctly.

Comment: `strcpy(raHash, md_value)` makes no sense. There is no guarantee that calculated digest has a zero-octet to act as a string terminator.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to dynamic allocation in *any* of this. The whole point of this exercise it to brute-force generating random, equal-length alpha-numeric strings, digesting them, and stopping when you fine one that matches the first three octets.

- No string conversions are required
- One like-sized message buffer (matching the size of your test message) can be used.
- You can reuse the digest context. No need to keep allocating and destroying it.
- `getit` is ultimately pointless except to tally up a counter.

The result is something like this:

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

void randString(size_t length, char* s);

int main()
{
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned char md_test[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int md_len, i;

    char msg[] = "Test Message";

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    const EVP_MD *md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256");
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

    EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, msg, sizeof msg-1);
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);

    printf("Digest is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
        printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
    printf("\n");

    int counter = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        ++counter;
        char rand_msg[sizeof msg];
        randString(sizeof msg - 1, rand_msg);
        EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
        EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, rand_msg, sizeof rand_msg - 1);
        EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_test, &md_len);
        if (memcmp(md_test, md_value, 3) == 0)
        {
            printf("Match found: %s\nAttempts: %d\n", rand_msg, counter);
            printf("Digest is: ");
            for (i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
                printf("%02x", md_test[i]);
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output (varies, obviously)**

```
Digest is: b67d1b3ab0d839eb8bc1156b8717bb441c897fcab323374e2ae530a40632feba
Match found: nPbeGgsZcNoo
Attempts: 9570596
Digest is: b67d1bcdab5d05a8712a8cd4c99b5bf683fdcefcf43fc453f852f4ff14b28a39
```

Answer (score 0):

Friends I figured it out.

I never used free(qt) so eventually, it ran out of memory to allocate after looping!

Comment: There is good advice suggested to you in comments and possible solution, simple info from valgrind ... Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) at 0x4C31068: strcpy. Think about it.